# Should vinyl plank flooring be caulked around a wall pipe?

Tags: basement, pipe, vinyl-flooring

I am installing Vinyl Plank flooring with a moisture barrier underlayment on our concrete basement floor. The basement was unfinished, but is now being finished. I installed the flooring all through out including near a wall pipe drain from the kitchen above. No trim and nothing else yet is down.

Today, there was a blockage in the pipe and water flowed out onto the floor and under the floor. I am wondering how I should prevent it from going under the floor again. I do plan to get the pipe checked as to why it did that since it is the first time I can ever recall it overflowing like that.

[image: Wall Pipe]

[image: Flooring in front of pipe]

Comment: it's still not clear which leaked, but there's no reason water should come out of either of those. At any rate, this isn't a flooring issue. You're never going to seal around the perimeter of your room.

Comment: No.  (assuming it's a floating floor)   The planks need to expand and contract slightly with changes in temperature.  If you fasten one side down, you have a potential for future problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, sure, but caulk isn't going to make your floor a boat. It'll slow things down somewhat, but even self-sealing floors have small flaws in their water-holding ability. A flood is a flood, and no plank floor is designed to manage that. You'll have water underneath with any serious spill.

If you do caulk, I suggest clear silicone. It'll take on the color of the floor and be nearly invisible. Otherwise focus on the plumbing issue and do what you can to prevent recurrence. If the drain isn't critical, cap it. If possible, put a one-way check valve device in it.

Comment: I think without the pics it may have been confusing on what was asked. It is a wall pipe and not a floor drain. I

Comment: That doesn't change my answer, which is that this isn't a flooring issue.

Comment: If I am understanding, correctly, you would say there really isn't any need to caulk around the pipe at the bottom since it will seep under anyway